# smooth window.scrollBy() is not working well in ios, it makes jumps not scrolling

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx, react-bootstrap

i am using window.scrollBy() and it works perfectly on pc's however it makes jumps on the mobile phones.
here is an example of my call

```
scrollTextAboutUs= () => {
    var scrollTo=document.getElementById("AboutUs").getClientRects()[0].y-this.state.headerHeight
    window.scrollBy({top: scrollTo, left: 0, behavior: 'smooth'})
  }
```

Comment: here is my full [code](https://ideone.com/987aSX)